# Use of studying different algorithm mechanism for sorting when STL does it crisply

Tags: c++, stl

I mean, what is the use of studying different sorting algorithms when it can be done with the help of a single line in c++ using STL?
Is it just for the sake of knowing (or any other reason)?

Comment: Ask that to your professor/teacher please.

Comment: You're expected to know how to sort, because you're expected to have studied algorithms, and sorting is usually one of the first types of algorithms you learn. (circular reasoning, I know). And if you haven't studied algorithms, then you probably don't understand algorithmic complexity. And if you don't understand algorithmic complexity, then you write slow programs. Maybe if CS text authors would all agree to put sorting at the end of their books, you wouldn't have to learn it.

Comment: STL sort won't do a very good job trying to sort a list of 16 billion items on a system with only 4GB of memory. You'll want to know about external merge sorts if you ever run across that sort of situation.

Comment: You have to learn how to think *somehow*. This is why they teach you stuff that requires thought. By studying how problems have been solved in the past you learn how to solve problems of the future.

Comment: Here is a discussion on the topic [here at quora.com](https://www.quora.com/If-advanced-algorithms-and-data-structures-are-never-used-in-industry-then-why-learn-them). The summary is, because you will never understand why your code runs fast/slowly unless you understand the underlying algorithms that it is using to get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's comparable (i think) to knowing all of the different STL containers. Think about all the different options you have just too store objects, priority queue's, vectors, arrays, deques, stacks, maps, sets, etc... The list goes on. A naive programmer may simply use a `std::vector` for everything. I mean everyone is always saying such good things about `std::vector`, it manages it's own size, it's extremely fast at adding new elements, etc... The list goes on. But do you use `std::vector` for all your containers, i certainty hope not! The same logic apply's too knowing the various sorting algorithms, their are cases where the built in sorting mechanisms are simply inadequate, and you must not only know how to recognize when this situation occurs but be able too come up with a clean solution.

*Just because the STL handles many operations (such as sorting) effectively it does not mean it will handle ALL situations effecively*

Comment: Upvoted since your answer is simply better than mine :). But I'll still leave mine in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Learning different ways to do things and the benefits/tradeofs they provide is often helpful.

For (an extreme) example; if you are sorting a container of at most 5 elements, then the lowly bubble sort may out-perform std::sort (which is most likely quicksort). So if this is something you do millions of times each second then you'd lose out with std::sort.

There is never (or at least "very rarely") a single " best" solution to a problem. So learning about the alternatives and the tradeoffs is valuable.